What is category theory's perspective on (binary) subdirect products and congruence-permutability?
I'm trying to understand congruence-permutability from the perspective of category theory. The most straightforward way to do this is to directly translate the condition that it is named for: $\theta_2 \circ \theta_1 = \theta_1 \lor \theta_2 = \theta_1 \circ \theta_2$. So I fiddled with internal equivalence relations and roof diagrams, as one does, and I ended up getting a condition that looked very similar to a technical lemma from Burris and Sankappanavar (Lemma 10.1) due to I. Fleischer [1955]. It turns out that Burris and Sankappanavar actually did not state the full strength of what Fleischer proved, which is what I ended up reproving using abstract nonsense: a variety is congruence-permutable if and only if every pushout of an internal left-total right-total binary relation is also a pullback diagram. Of course, an "internal left-total right-total binary relation" is simply a binary subdirect product. But I feel like there would have to be a better way to view this, because as it is, the way I've described a subdirect product using the language of category theory is horrendous, and relies on elements. (I would say "epimorphism" instead of "left-total" and "right-total", but I am pretty sure that epimorphisms need not be surjective in varieties.)
The question: What is category theory's perspective on (binary) subdirect products and congruence-permutability? In particular, is there a nicer way to describe what makes a roof diagram one that would come from a subdirect product? Alternatively, is there a nicer way to describe the condition of congruence-permutability on a variety?
Do be warned that although I am aware of the modern perspective of finitary monads on $\text{Set}$ to do universal algebra nowadays, I am very uninformed about most of it, so if there is some monad-based perspective, that would also be appreciated. That being said, I don't see an obvious way to attack this from the side of the influence of a Mal'cev term on the monad, but if y'all do, that would be very cool.

For groups this was first proved by Wedder Homomorphism of Groups
J. H. M. Wedderburn
Annals of Mathematics
Vol. 42, No. 2 (Apr., 1941), pp. 486-487 (2 pages)
